# How to auto detect language from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

Is there a way to auto detect a programming language from a string?

I am trying to use [Prism.JS](https://prismjs.com/index.html#basic-usage) but can't seem to find anything on it.

If there isn't a way to do so in Prism.JS directly, is there a native Javascript solution?

```
var string = '.element { font-family: serif; }' 

//returns CSS
```

Comment: What all languages do you need to detect?

Comment: @VinaySharma All the main ones. [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) does this automatically, but I am currently using `Prism.js` which doesn't appear to have an option to do so

Comment: `if (x < 0) { x = x + 1 }` is valid JavaScript, valid C, valid Java... What do you want to return for that string? All potential languages, any of them or a specific one?

Comment: @secan As shown in the example, it should return the name of the language, not if it's valid or not. This is done through Regex I believe. `Highlight.js` does so but it is built directly into their library. It takes in any random string, and returns `css`,`javascript`,`python`, etc. This should do the same

Comment: @freedomn-m A single possibility*.

`console.log("Hello world"); - returns Javascript`.
`System.out.prinln(el) - returns Java`.

Comment: Given @secan 's example, there isn't a "single" option.

Comment: @freedomn-m They were clearly separated, your fake quote puts them into one piece of code whereas I separated them. Stop being difficult. It should take in a string, and return whatever language that is. That's it. In cases where the syntax is the same across multiple languages and it doesn't know which one to pick, it can just return any.

Comment: To answer your question: "is there a native js solution" - clearly not as why would js be interested in java/c++/vb.net/ruby etc and if there was, there wouldn't be multiple libraries to do this.

Comment: @trippyyyreddd, what I meant is that the string `if (x < 0) { x = x + 1 }` has no unique identification: it can be JavaScript, Java, C, C++, C# and a number of other languages. In a case like that, what are you supposed to return? Should you return all possible languages, an arbitrarily selected one from all the potential ones, a specific one?

Comment: @trippyyyreddd yeah, mea culpa, I read it differently from how you intended it  so deleted my comment.  Not being intentionally difficult, just misread.

Comment: @secan In that case, it's fine to just return any of them, or perhaps just the first one it identifies

Comment: @trippyyyreddd all the *main ones* is vague. Are you looking to detect some specific set of languages or all?

Answer (score 2):

Use [lang-detector](https://github.com/ts95/lang-detector) library. Here is a [DEMO](https://hosein2398.github.io/lang-detect/).

Or you could use [HighlightJs](https://highlightjs.org/). [highlightAuto](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#highlightauto-code-languagesubset) can detect language for you. It can detect more languages than lang-detector.

Comment: I use Prism.Js - https://prismjs.com/index.html#basic-usage. Is there a way to do so in Prism, not Highlight.Js?

Comment: according to my finding, prism doesn't detect language.

Comment: Correct, Prism only highlights, it does auto-detect.